# Laravel 8 - npm run dev showing ELIFECYCLE in production but working perfectly in dev

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

We're encountering this error when trying to run npm run dev or npm run production:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'development' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.18
3 info using node@v14.21.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'predevelopment', 'development', 'postdevelopment' ]
5 info lifecycle @~predevelopment: @
6 info lifecycle @~development: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~development: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~development: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/secretuser/maplemain/node_modules/.bin:/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/secretuser/maplemain/node_modules/.bin:/home/secretuser/perl5/bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin:/home/secretuser/bin
9 verbose lifecycle @~development: CWD: /home/secretuser/maplemain
10 silly lifecycle @~development: Args: [ '-c', 'mix' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~development: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~development: Failed to exec development script
13 verbose stack Error: @ development: `mix`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1088:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:296:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /home/secretuser/maplemain
16 verbose Linux 3.10.0-1160.92.1.el7.x86_64
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "development"
18 verbose node v14.21.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.18
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ development: `mix`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ development script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

The thing is, in our staging/dev environment, it runs perfectly and without any issues.

Both staging and production environments are running:
PHP 8
Laravel 8
npm 6.14.18
node v14.21.3
CentOS 7

Production environment is running cPanel/WHM while staging does not. We believe that this is significant and that probably a security feature in WHM might be causing this.

Things we tried:

- Deleting node_modules and package-lock.json, npm cache clean --force and then running composer update and npm install
- When we run npm run dev once or twice - it seems like it's using up either all available memory or all creates lots of processes kind of like a fork bomb and we end up having to reboot the server
- Upgraded npm to 9.7.2

npm is creating core (memory dump files). As you can see, the error is not very detailed so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not surprisingly, explaining this problem here helped us connect the dots and realize what caused the issue. I'm posting this answer in hopes this helps others because we spent many hours on this issue.

The cause of the issue was the Fork Bomb Protection setting in WHM. It was turned on and as a result, ulimit -n (aka max open files) was set to 100.

npm run dev/production apparently needs to open more files than 100 so this caused the problem.

How to fix this:

1. Disable Fork Bomb Protection in WHM
2. Go to /etc/security/limits.conf and add these lines if they're not already present:

```
[USERNAME]        soft    nofile          2048
[USERNAME]        hard    nofile          2048
Obviously - change [USERNAME] with the name of the user you want to set the limit for
```

Close all open SSH sessions of [USERNAME] and try running npm run dev or npm run production again.

Good luck!